# Connecting multiple tables, better approach RDBMS

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, activerecord, rdbms

I am developing an app for scheduling appointments with beauty masters.

First picture shows the schema I have now. I am calling master from appointment through service. I wonder, if adding **master_id** to appointment itself (second picture) would be faster. Is adding another foreign key to appointment it an efficient change or waste column?

[image: Currenly]

[image: Alternative]

Comment: The rule is the direction of the relationship. 1 to n (1 master can have many clients), then key of the n table must be present as foreign key in 1 (client table)

Comment: @JaimeDrq, I am about to do the opposite, i.e. calling master from appointment. Currently I am invoking Service, which has foreign key for master.

Comment: There are no calls/invocations here. Find out what a FK is--it says subrow values in one table appear in another as a PK/UNIQUE.

Answer (score 2):

The two models are different.

The first says that each appointment has a service, and each service has a master.  Hence, each appointment must have the same master as its service.

The second model says that each appoint has a service *and* a master.  The service also has a master, but nothing guarantees that the two masters are the same.

I would implement the model that best represents the entities I am using.

For performance, you should first focus on getting the data right, then think about indexes, partitioning and how you structure queries.  If none of that gets the performance you need, then you can think about how to change the physical data model.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I will stick to the first logic, because the master is the owner of the service.